# Parsing XML from GData Youtube error

Tags: xml, api, parsing, gdata

I'm getting a very annoying error when parsing data from gdata api and I don't really understand why it's getting an error here. The xml is straight from the gdata api.

```
 Dim Document As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(Response.Html)
```

Error is: '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 1, position 1142.

Here is the XML inputted

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" gd:etag="W/&quot;DEMHQXg5cSp7I2A9WhBWGE0.&quot;">
    <id>tag:youtube.com,2008:video:OtyPaMYuC0Q:comments</id>
    <updated>2013-04-12T22:40:30.629Z</updated>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment" />
    <logo>http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif</logo>
    <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/OtyPaMYuC0Q/comments" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/OtyPaMYuC0Q/comments" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/OtyPaMYuC0Q/comments/batch" />
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/OtyPaMYuC0Q/comments?start-index=1&amp;max-results=1" />
    <link rel="service" type="application/atomsvc+xml" href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/OtyPaMYuC0Q/comments?alt=atom-service" />
    <link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/OtyPaMYuC0Q/comments?start-index=2&amp;max-results=1" />
    <author>
        <name>YouTube</name>
        <uri>http://www.youtube.com/</uri>
    </author>
    <generator version="2.1" uri="http://gdata.youtube.com">YouTube data API</generator>
    <openSearch:totalResults>9284</openSearch:totalResults>
    <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
    <openSearch:itemsPerPage>1</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
    <entry gd:etag="W/&quot;DkQNRn47eCp7I2A9WhBWGE0.&quot;">
        <id>tag:youtube.com,2008:video:OtyPaMYuC0Q:comment:pGfDzo6Y7ksUb5ICc3XxO4jP7npln-jyFXhsyFfp3H8</id>
        <published>2013-04-12T22:06:37.000Z</published>
        <updated>2013-04-12T22:06:37.000Z</updated>
        <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment" />
        <title>No Scrubs, What You ...</title>
        <content>No Scrubs, What You Know, Say My Name, Sweet Dreams... etc.  I wrote some crap for Michael &amp; Janet Jackson, Rihanna, Chris Brown, etc.  I've worked with a lot of people who were once famous, or who may still be famous.  I'm very proud if someone started off with me and went on to achieve great things.  Because it's always good because﻿ then I can count on them, possibly in the future.  I wrote most of the first Lady Gaga album, beats and lyrics.  I was very proud of those songs.</content>
        <link rel="related" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/OtyPaMYuC0Q" />
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtyPaMYuC0Q" />
        <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/OtyPaMYuC0Q/comments/pGfDzo6Y7ksUb5ICc3XxO4jP7npln-jyFXhsyFfp3H8" />
        <author>
            <name>nameless777</name>
            <uri>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/nameless777</uri>
            <yt:userId>vBwfm3xuTJYlHobnMa0Oaw</yt:userId>
        </author>
        <yt:videoid>OtyPaMYuC0Q</yt:videoid>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, for some reason I had to load using the stream.